# how to keep html5 footer at bottom(below input buttons) when keyboard opens to input text

Tags: footer

I'm developing a smartphone app in HTML5, CSS3 & Javascript. I'm using phoneGap and PhoneGap Build to create native code. The problem is that the pages look good until the user needs to enter text. The keyboard opens and pushes the footer up above the keyboard into the text box covering the input button(s) below the text box.

```
<footer>
<ul class="flink">
<li><a href="link1.html" class="first active"><img src="images/link1.png"/><span    class="ftext">Link 1</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Link2.html" class="first active"><img src="images/link2.png"/><span class="ftext">Link 2</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Link3.html" class="first active"><img src="images/link3.png"/><span class="ftext">Link 3</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Link4.html" class="first active"><img src="images/link4.png"/><span class="ftext">Link 4</span></a></li>
<li><a href="Link5.html" class="first active"><img src="images/link5.png"/><span class="ftext">Link 5</span></a></li>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer { position:fixed; bottom:0; width:100%; display:inline-block;background:#000; }
footer ul { margin:0px; width:100%; float:left;}
footer ul li { margin:0px; width:20%; .width:auto;display:inline; float:left; text-align:center; height:auto;}
footer ul li a { margin:0px; width:100%; float:left; height:auto; font:normal 11px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; padding:10px 1px; background:#000; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;}
footer ul li a.first { margin-right:1%; width:99%;}
footer ul li a img { width:30px; height:30px;}
footer ul li a .ftext { display:block; margin-top:1px;}
footer ul li a:hover {background: rgb(75,75,75);
```

Comment: You'll need to hide the footer

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have the footer at the end of the page instead of sticking it to the bottom of the device?

Comment: The problem with the footer at the end of the page is that the footer might not sit on the bottom of the page. It will just sit right beneath what ever was before it. Then background would be visible and the footer would change position depending on what ever else is on the page, the footer wouldn't sit at the bottom of the screen.